# MongoDB C# Driver - how to store _id as ObjectId but map to string Id property?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm having trouble getting my model to represent an entity's `Id` property as a string but have it auto-generated and represented internally by MongoDb as a native `ObjectId`.

```
class Account
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

class AccountStore
{
    static AccountStore()
    {
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Account>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);

            // map Id property here
        });
    }

    public void Save(Account account)
    {
        _accounts.Save(account);
    }
}
```

For the line `// map Id property here` in the above code, I've tried numerous different ways of configuring the Id mapping and none have worked. The ways I have tried, and the associated exceptions that are thrown when I call the `Save` method, are:

```
// Exception: No IdGenerator found.
cm.IdMemberMap
  .SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);

// Exception: No IdGenerator found.
cm.IdMemberMap
  .SetRepresentation(BsonType.String);

// Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' to type 'System.String'.
cm.IdMemberMap
  .SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)
  .SetIdGenerator(ObjectIdGenerator.Instance);

// Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' to type 'System.String'.
cm.IdMemberMap
  .SetRepresentation(BsonType.String)
  .SetIdGenerator(ObjectIdGenerator.Instance);

// Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' to type 'System.String'.
cm.IdMemberMap
  .SetIdGenerator(ObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought this was a standard use case for id handling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply BsonRepresentation attribute by convention when using MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043266/how-to-apply-bsonrepresentation-attribute-by-convention-when-using-mongodb)

Comment: There is a convention which you can try to use I post it in this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621787/4319938

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This has changed, I'm using the latest 1.x driver (Nuget package `<package id="mongocsharpdriver" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />`) and instead of using `SetRepresentation` you set the serialiser.

```
public class RegistrationAttempt
{
    public string AttemptId { get; set; }
}

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<RegistrationAttempt>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapIdProperty(c => c.AttemptId)
        .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
        .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
});
```

Comment: @I've rolled back the edit which changed the version number of the driver. Although the package says 2.0.0 I'm using the legacy driver because the 2.0 driver doesn't have the support for IQueryable yet. However, the package `mongocsharpdriver` driver does pull in the latest driver packages so I could be mistaken and using some combination of both. I don't think so though because I get a warning that part of my code is using an obsolete API

Comment: god dammit! I've been using ObjectIdGenerator instead of StringObjectIdGenerator. thank you! Just to add, This works in version 2.4 of the driver

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer:

```
cm.IdMemberMap
  .SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)
  .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
```

This allows me to save as a native ObjectId and still have the Id represented in C# as a string. As a small gotcha, the id must be parsed before being queried upon:

```
public Account GetAccountById(string id)
{
    return _accounts.FindOneById(ObjectId.Parse(id));
}
```

**Edit May 2015**
Apparently the driver has changed since I wrote this answer. The other answer above is correct for newer versions, but this answer can still be referred to if using a legacy version of the driver.

Comment: Is this the 2.0 driver? I don't have the SetRepresentation function

Comment: No it's changed now, I'll provide an up to date answer for people looking today.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want that very same kind of mapping across a whole range of entities without the need to repeat yourself over and over again you might want to use a convention:

```
public class 
StringObjectIdIdGeneratorConventionThatWorks : 
ConventionBase, IPostProcessingConvention
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Applies a post processing modification to the class map.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="classMap">The class map.</param>
    public void PostProcess(BsonClassMap classMap)
    {
        var idMemberMap = classMap.IdMemberMap;
        if (idMemberMap == null || idMemberMap.IdGenerator != null)
            return;
        if (idMemberMap.MemberType == typeof(string))
        {
            idMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance).SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
        }
    }
}
```

...and then use it in lieu of all custom mappings:

```
ConventionPack cp = new ConventionPack();
cp.Add(new StringObjectIdIdGeneratorConventionThatWorks());

ConventionRegistry.Register("TreatAllStringIdsProperly", cp, _ => true);
```