# MongoDB C# does not generate a value for _id/ObjectId when using StringObjectIdGenerator

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to follow the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351675/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-how-to-store-id-as-objectid-but-map-to-string-id-prope), but something is not working right. I've implemented the following:

My Model

```
public class MyModel { 
       public string MyModelId { get; set; } 
       //Other properties 
 }
```

My mapping

```
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyModel>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.MapIdProperty(c => c.MyModelId)
                    .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
                    .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));

        });
```

My Insert

```
        if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(MyModel)))
        {
            //Do the mapping above
        }

        var collection = RetrieveCollection("MyModels"); //method used to retrieve an IMongoCollection from the database.
        var bsonDoc = model.ToBsonDocument(); //model is an argument passed in to the method of type MyModel

        collection.InsertOne(bsonDoc);
```

Every time it gets done doing the InsertOne() operation, there is no element in the BsonDocument for MyModelId. Furthermore, there is an element for _id in the BsonDocument that is always set to "BsonNull". Then if I try to insert again, MongoDB throws a "  E11000 duplicate key error collection:" error, presumably because one already exists with a value of "BsonNull".

If I comment out my mapping, an ObjectId value gets created for _id, but then I cannot deserialize back to MyModel.

Why doesn't the StringObjectIdGenerator actually generate an ID?

Answer (score 3):

Alright, with the some educated guessing after view [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223894/mongodb-net-not-generating-id-on-upsert?lq=1), I tried the following:

```
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyModel>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.MapIdProperty(c => c.MyModelId)
                .SetIgnoreIfDefault(true) //added this line
                .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
                .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));

    });
```

This seems to have resolved the issue. When inserting the BsonDocument, I still saw the "_id" field, instead of "MyModelId". However the "_id" field had a value in it. Furthermore when I retrieved the value from the collection, and deserialized it back to a MyModel object the MyModelId property was populated by the value previously saw in "_id".

Comment: Have used hours on this, your approach almost led me to the root cause, now I just have issues with classes without ID's, also this aproach won't work if you inherit classes from a "MongoObject" class, if that underlying class is the one having the ID.

But thanks, this is much