# MongoDB: " '' is not a valid 24 digit hex string " when using classmap

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a C# entity like this, and I'm trying to persist it in MongoDB:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Because the `Id` is a `string`, I need to add `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` as an attribute to my `Id` property. This works fine. However, I'm trying replace this attribute with a classmap, like so:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // More init code...

        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyEntity>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.IdMemberMap.SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
        });
    }
}
```

With this classmap, MongoDB does not seem to understand what to do with the `Id`. When using the attribute, a new `_id` is generated, as should be. But when using the classmap, an error is thrown: `'' is not a valid 24 digit hex string`. What am I doing wrong in configuring the classmap?

Debugging information: When I inspect the `cm.IdMemberMap`, it is mapped to the `string Id` property, so that works, no `[BsonId]` is needed. And both with the attribute and the classmap, the value of `Id` is `''` (empty string) just before sending it to the DB, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I have a clue.  If digits are pack two per byte than it is 12 bytes.  Found following : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/?force_isolation=true#objectid.  The link show they have a 4-byte timestamp, a 5-byte random value and a 3 byte incrementing counter.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: No `IdGenerator` was set, so this additional initialization was needed:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<HubPersistenceModel>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.IdMemberMap
        .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
        .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
});
```

For reference, I found the answer here: [MongoDB C# Driver - how to store _id as ObjectId but map to string Id property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351675/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-how-to-store-id-as-objectid-but-map-to-string-id-prope)

Strange detail is the documentation (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/bson/mapping/) says the `StringObjectIdGenerator` is applied automatically, so this extra configuration should not be needed. Don't know why it's still needed.